# Using a JAX-WS client, how do you get the SOAP header from a response?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, soaphandler

Using a JAX-WS client, how do you get the SOAP header from a response?

I'm guessing you can do it using the `handleMessage` method of a `SOAPHandler`, but I feel like I'm missing some more obvious, straight-forward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SOAPHandler you can get all the soap message(getting the header). This is the most straight-forward way. If you want I can get a code example for you.

Comment: No example needed for me.  That's already the way I'm doing it.  I just needed validation that it's the "normal" approach.  Thanks.